# How to solve this Diophantine equation？

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

$$
\frac{1}{m^{2}} - \frac{1}{n^{2}} = \frac{1}{p^{2}} - \frac{1}{q^{2}}
\neq 0
$$

I guess $\left | m \right | = \left | p \right | $ and $\left | n \right | = \left | q \right | $.

Is there any way to exclude other situations?

Comment: a perfectly good question combined with a perfectly good answer makes the downvote perfectly uncalled for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are counterexamples, e.g., take
$$
(m,n,p,q) = (100,156,65,75).
$$
Note that the equation can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{1}{m^{2}} + \frac{1}{q^{2}} = \frac{1}{p^{2}} + \frac{1}{n^{2}}
$$
This has infinitely many solutions with $\gcd(m,q,p,n)=1$, e.g., among
$$
(m,q,p,n)=(2k^2(2k^2-1),2k^2-1,k(2k^2-1),2k^2), k\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}.
$$